# How to query all fields in a row

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I know this is very simple, but I haven't used PHP/MySQL in a while and I have been reading other threads/php website and can't seem to get it.

How can I query a single row from a MySQL Table and print out all of the fields that have data in them? I need to exclude the NULL fields, and only add those that have data to an html list.

To clarify, I would like to display the field data without specifying the field names, just for the reason that I have a lot of fields and will not know which ones will be NULL or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've outlined requires 4 basic steps:

1. Connect to the database.
2. Query for a specific row.
3. Remove the null values from the result.
4. Create the html.

Step 1 is quite environment specific, so that we can safely skip here.

Step 2 - SQL

```
SELECT * from <tablename> WHERE <condition isolating single row>
```

Step 3 - PHP (assuming that $query represents the executed db query)

```
//convert the result to an array
$result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query);

//remove null values from the result array
$result_array = array_filter($result_array, 'strlen');
```

Step 4 - PHP

```
foreach ($result_array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value \n;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. However, I am getting an error. "Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home2/fragnetn/public_html/game2.php on line 121" Why would it read mysql_query's return as a bool value?

Comment: I'm guessing that either your SQL was malformed/failed or you forgot to convert the response to an array -- $result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query); -- prior to calling array_filter() upon it.

Comment: Yeah I realized my query was being passed a value to use for the WHERE that I hadn't actually set the value for yet. This is working fine now, although I am getting duplicates for each field. Does foreach loop twice for each, once for key and once for value or something?

Comment: Nevermind, sorted it by doing "mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);"

Answer (score 2):

Just `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE....` will do the trick.

To grab data from specific fields, it would be `SELECT field_1,field_2,field_3`....

Comment: I apologize, the issue I am having is that I have like 20 fields so rather than specify the name of each one, I would just like to loop through all pull the field data for each one that isn't null, rather than specifying it by name.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a string which represent mysql query. Then there is function in php named `mysql_query()`. Call this function with above string as parameter. It will return you all results. [Here are some examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this...

First connect to your sql... [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Now make a query and assign it to a variable...

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT column_name1, column_name2 FROM tablename");
```

If you want to retrieve a single row use `LIMIT 1`

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT column_name1, column_name2 FROM tablename LIMIT 1");
```

If you want to fetch all the columns just use `*` instead of column names and if you want to leave some rows where specific column data is `blank` you can do it like this

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column_name4 !=''");

Now fetch the array out of it and loop through the array like this..

```
while($show_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $show_rows['column_name1'];
   echo $show_rows['column_name2'];
}
```

If you don't want to include the column names in the while loop, you could do this:

```
while($show_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   foreach( $show_rows as $key => $val )
   {
       echo $show_rows[$key];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to echo in the while loop without having the column name? That is the whole issue I am having but don't think I explained it very well :)

Comment: You have to use column name as it is `array key name`

Comment: So there isn't any way to query for all row fields that are not null, and then just display them such as "echo $field[X]", with X being the index of each field pulled?

Comment: @BrettPowell You need to use column names and it is usefull if you are arranging your data in different columns so you can echo it appropriately...

Comment: The questioner inquired: "How can I query a __single row__ from a MySQL Table" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @coderabbi Do you see edited question??? and you did explained him the whole procedure as I did

Comment: I have been working on adding this, trying to sort out why its not working before I select it as answered. Thank you for the edit!